# how to use javascript variable in php inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

i am trying to fetch JavaScript variable "i" in my PHP Code within a JavaScript function in the below code, I find problem in retrieving records, either first record or the last record repeats instead of all records in database.. can you guys help me out ?
Thanks

```
      <?php
         $query21 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM register");
         $nr      = mysqli_num_rows($query21);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query21)) {
         $results[] = $row;
             }

        ?>




<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


var intervalID = 0;
    var time = 10;

    MsgPop.displaySmall = true;
    MsgPop.position = "bottom-right";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var test = MsgPop.open({
        Type:            "success",
        AutoClose:        true,
        Content:        "Welcome to MsgPop!"});

        MsgPop.live();
    });

  function showMessages(){    

        var n = '<?php
echo $nr;
?>';

        var i = 0;


        while (i < n){

                var name = '<?php
echo $results[i]['name'];
?>';



        MsgPop.open({
        Type:            "success",
        Content:        name,
        AutoClose:        false});
    i++;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create a php file which return same array. File contain

```
$query21 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM register");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query21);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query21)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($results);
exit;
```

Now you have to call this file using ajax from your javascript code.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sql.php",  //your file url

})
.done(function (data) {
    //you get your array data(json format)
});
```

now you get that array in ajax response in json format and you can do anything with this data.

Answer (score 0):

**Impossible:** PHP is a server side language that runs only at server. but javascript is a client side script it only run at your browser only.  Php only gives response depends on your requests. The roll of php is end at server. But the javascript work with your response only, that is javascript can work at browser only.

Comment: But when i use  var name = '<?php
echo $results[0]['name']; 
?>'; or  var name = '<?php
echo $results[1]['name'];
?>';or so on i can retrieve records .. but i couldnt with variables .. if this is impossible then how to ? any other ways

Comment: @Arjit cover your script variable to php variables.

Comment: Or covert php array to json and work with javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could try using AJAX, or else it isn't happening. Like said PHP is server-side only...  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot fetch javascript variables. You should try another strategy.

At the server side (PHP), try to store $resuts in a javascript variable.

```
var results = '<?php echo json_encode($results); ?>';
```

Then at the browser side, try to access the data with javascript functions.

```
var name = results[i]['name'];
```

Comment: Getting Array to String conversion error if i use that.. as $results is stored in Array when we retrieve data.. so that wil not be possible i guess...